# Include js in php file

Tags: javascript, php

I have normal alert in my code, instead I need sweet alert as an alternative.

But the problem is my file is pure `Php` file, and there is no html tag to include the `sweetalert.js` file, hence it is not working.

```
<?php
    // ...
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js">';
                echo 'swal("Mobile Number not registered.Please login through Email");';
                echo '</script>';
?>
```

Comment: you shouldn't mix PHP + JS fullstop, you should call it in a template/js file - why is it generated from PHP (not in a lecturer tone - more of a asking, sometimes there is a valid reason for HTML generation from server)

Answer (score 2):

The text content of a `script` element gets *ignored*, if the script element has a `src` set. The JS code you are dynamically outputting here via PHP, should not have worked to begin with, even if it was “static” instead.

Something like

```
echo '<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>';
echo '<script>swal("Mobile Number not registered.Please login through Email");</script>';
```

would *work* … but it’s not really nice. You should not output larger parts of static HTML via echo in the first place, but properly “break out” of the PHP code part, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

A proper way to do this:

```
<?php

// some PHP stuff here

?>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script>swal("Mobile Number not registered.Please login through Email");</script>
<?php

// more PHP stuff here
```

Comment: Then check what your browser console has to say.

Comment: There is no information on the colsole window :
If i write the following in the console, it works perfectly fine,
swal("Mobile Number not registered.Please login through Email");

But the same part of code in the php file,doesn't show up anything!!!

Comment: So what does the generated HTML output look like?